# Typescript move object horizontally

Tags: javascript, typescript

Im trying to make a game with typescript and I'm trying to move the cat with the up, down, left and right arrows on my keyboard. Now I can only move the cat up and down. Does someone know what's wrong with my code and why I cant move it left and right? What I did is use and event listener to look if the key is pressed or not. If it is then in the cases you can see in which case it is. I gave it both vertical and horizontal speed. I feel like either something is missing or I did something wrong. I dont get any errors.

```js
export class Cat{
    // Fields
    private x : number = 0
    private y : number = 0
    private div: HTMLElement

    private verticalSpeed : number = 0
    private horizontalSpeed : number = 0
   

    public getBoundingRect() : DOMRect {
        return this.div.getBoundingClientRect()
    }

    constructor(tagName: string) {
        console.log("Cat was created!")

        // Add the event listeners to the window for the keyboard events
        window.addEventListener("keydown",  (e: KeyboardEvent) => this.onKeyDown(e))
        window.addEventListener("keyup",    (e: KeyboardEvent) => this.onKeyUp(e))

        this.create()
        
        this.y = Math.floor(Math.random() * (window.innerWidth - this.div.clientWidth))
        this.y = Math.floor(Math.random() * (window.innerHeight - this.div.clientHeight))
        this.x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (window.innerWidth - this.div.clientWidth))
        this.x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (window.innerHeight - this.div.clientHeight))
    }

    private create() : void {
        this.div = document.createElement("cat")
        document.body.appendChild(this.div)   
    }

    public update() : void {
        // Add the vertical speed to the y-value
        this.y += this.verticalSpeed

        this.x += this.horizontalSpeed

        // Draw the shark on the right coordinate (x, y)
        this.div.style.transform = `translate(${this.x}px, ${this.y}px)`
    }

    private onKeyDown(e: KeyboardEvent): void {
        // log the keyboard
        // console.log(e.key)

        // Check if the key in the event (e.key) matches the desired input
        switch (e.key) {
            // When the "ArrowUp" key is pressed
            case "ArrowUp":
                // Give the vertical speed a negative value
                this.verticalSpeed = -5
                break
            // When the "ArrowDown" key is pressed
            case "ArrowDown":
                // Give the vertical speed a positive value
                this.verticalSpeed = 5
                break

            case "ArrowLeft":
                // Give the horizontal speed a neegative value
                this.horizontalSpeed = -5
                break

            case "ArrowRight":
                // Give the horizontal speed a positive value
                this.horizontalSpeed = -5
                break
        }
    }

    private onKeyUp(e: KeyboardEvent): void {
        // Check if ArrowUp or ArrowDown key has been released
        if(e.key == "ArrowUp" || e.key == "ArrowDown" || e.key == "ArrowLeft" || e.key == "ArrowRight" ){
            // Make the vertical speed 0
            this.verticalSpeed = 0
            //make the horizontal speed 0
            this.horizontalSpeed = 0
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `case "ArrowRight": // Give the vertical speed a positive value this.horizontalSpeed = -5` wrong copy/paste?

Comment: sorry that was wrong i changed it